# Why numpy slicing will produce one-dimension array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm learning numpy from a YouTube tutorial. In a video he demonstrated that

```
wine_data_arr[:, 0].shape
```

where `wine_data_arr` are a two dimensional numpy array imported from `sklearn`. And the result is `(178,)`, and he said "*it is a one dimensional array*". But in math for example this

```
[1,2,3]
```

can represent a 1 by 3 matrix, which has dimension `2`. So my question is why `wine_data_arr[:, 0]` is a one dimension array? I guess this definition must be useful in some situation. So what's *that* situation?

Try to be more specific: when writing `wine_data_arr[:, 0]` I provide **two** arguments, i.e. `:` and `0` and the result is **one** dimension. When I write `wine_data_arr[:, (0,4)]`, I **still provide two** arguments `:` and `(0,4)`, a tuple, and the result is **two** dimension. Why not both produce two dimension matrix?

Comment: Compare `wine_data_arr[:,0]` with `wine_data_arr[:, 0:1]`. This works analogously to lists. `x[0]` gives you a single element of the list, while `x[0:1]` gives you another (possibly shorter) list. The integer index `0` gives you a lower-dimension slice, while `0:1` selects a "subset" of the original object with the same dimensions.

Comment: Mathematicaly, a one-dimensional vector is still distinct from a two-dimensional matrix, even if they are *isomorphic* to each other and their representation looks similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if they "look" the same, a vector is not the same as a matrix. Consider:

```
>>> np.array([1,2,3,4])
array([1, 2, 3,4])
>>> np.matrix([1,2,3,4])
matrix([[1, 2, 3,4]])
>>> np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
matrix([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]])
```

When slicing a two-dimensional array like

```
>>> wine_data_arr = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
>>> wine_data_arr
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

you can request a lower-dimensional component (a single row or column) using an integer index

```
>>> wine_data_arr[:,0]
array([1, 4, 7])
>>> wine_data_arr[0,:]
array([1, 2, 3])
```

or a same-dimensional "piece" using a slice index:

```
>>> wine_data_arr[:, 0:1]
array([[1],       
       [4],
       [7]])
```

If you use *two* integer indices, you get a single zero-dimensional element of the array:

```
>>> wine_data_arr[0,0]
1
```

Comment: OK I'm stupid I forgot to read your comments under my OP first :) So it's not about _one point_ but it's about how that point is selected. By exact index or set/list selection.

Comment: I will close with this: do you think of an `n x m` array as an `nm`-dimensional object because it has that many elements, or do you think of it as a 2-dimensional collection because each individual element can be selected using 2 indices? (There is some consistent way to reconcile these two views, and I am not even going to try to explain it because I will certainly explain it incorrectly.)

Comment: For future readers: notice that `wine_data_arr[[0,1], [0,1]].shape` is `(2,)` not `(2, 2)`. So you __HAVE TO__ use `:`-syntax, NOT `[, ]`-syntax.

Answer (score 2):

In `numpy` arrays can have 0, 1, 2 or more dimensions.  In contrast to MATLAB there isn't a 2d lower boundary.  Also `numpy` is generally consistent with Python lists, in display  and indexing. MATLAB generally follows linear algebra conventions, but I'm sure there are other math definitions for arrays and vectors.  In physics `vector` represents a point in space, or a direction, not a 2d 'column vector' or 'row vector'.

A list:

```
In [159]: alist = [1, 2, 3]
In [160]: len(alist)
Out[160]: 3
```

An array made from this list:

```
In [161]: arr = np.array(alist)
In [162]: arr.shape
Out[162]: (3,)
```

Indexing a list removes a level of nesting.  Scalar indexing an array removes a dimension.  See

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html

```
In [163]: alist[0]
Out[163]: 1
In [164]: arr[0]
Out[164]: 1
```

A 2d array:

```
In [166]: marr = np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2)
In [167]: marr
Out[167]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
```

Again, scalar indexing removes a dimension:

```
In [169]: marr[0,:]
Out[169]: array([0, 1])
In [170]: marr[:, 0]
Out[170]: array([0, 2])
In [172]: marr[1, 1]
Out[172]: 3
```

Indexing with a list or slice preserves the dimension:

```
In [173]: marr[0, [1]]
Out[173]: array([1])
In [174]: marr[0, 0:1]
Out[174]: array([0])
```

Count the `[]` to determine the dimensionality.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: this is a convention.

Before I go into further details, let me clarify that the "dimensionality" in NumPy, for example, is not the same as that in math. In math, `[1, 2, 3]` is a three-dimensional vector, or a one by three dimensional matrix if you want. However, here, the dimensionality really means the "physical" dimension of the array, i.e., how many axes are present in your array (or matrix, or tensor, etc.).

Now let me get back to your question of why "this" particular definition of array dimension is helpful. What I'm going to say next is somewhat philosophical and is my own take of it. Essentially, it all boils down to communication between programmers. For example, when you are reading the documentation of some Python code and wondering the dimensionality of the output array, sure the documentation can write "N x M x ..." and then carefully define what N, M, etc. are. But in many cases, just the number of axes (or the "dimensionality" referred to in NumPy) may be sufficient to inform you. In this case, the documentation becomes much cleaner and easier to read while providing enough information about the expected outcome.

Comment: Oh, you're right. the dimension of `[1,2,3]` is `(1, 3)`, which is not 2-dimension... Sorry, I haven't used linear algebra for so long...

Comment: So basically it's about counting the number of commas? Should I also care about those `[ ]` when the dimension is greater than or equal to `3`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's all about "counting the number of commas". Although you need to be more careful about the counting: one-tuple (e.g., ``(178,)``) has one comma, and two-tuple (e.g., ``(178, 3)``) also has one comma. But I think you get the point.

Not too sure about the second question about caring those ``[ ]``.